# How to retrieve data from two MySQL tables with multiple associations

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I got these two tables where one table is having multiple foreign keys to the second table.

Table `rankings`

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| search_text    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| first_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| second_item_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| third_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| forth_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `item`

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_code                 | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
```

One `ranking` record may have multiple association to `item` table using `first_item_id`, `second_item_id`, `third_item_id` or `forth_item_id` fields. I want to retrieve `ranking` records with the corresponding `item_code` instead of the `item.id`. What would be the most efficient way to do this if i have a big number of data?

PS: There are 10 associations to the `item.id` as `first_item_id` ... `tenth_item_id`. Im using Rails `ActiveRecord` ORM. Any workaround with that also fine.

Sample data `ranking`

`SELECT id,search_text,first_item_id as first,second_item_id as second,third_item_id as third,forth_item_id as forth from rankings limit 10;`

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| id | search_text | first | second | third | forth |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|  1 | test 1      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
|  2 | test 2      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
|  3 | test 3      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
|  4 | test 4      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Sample `item` data

`SELECT id,item_code from items limit 5;`

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | item_code  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | 125659     |
|      2 | 125660     |
|      3 | 125661     |
|      4 | 125662     |
+--------+------------+
```

Expected data

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| id | search_text | first | second | third | forth |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|  1 | test 1      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
|  2 | test 2      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
|  3 | test 3      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
|  4 | test 4      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: In general, your best bet is just joining to "item" four times here. Four is a reasonable number. If this is too costly from a performance standpoint make sure you have proper indexes or rethink your data model. However, if this is just a simplified case and you have dozens of items columns you can UNPIVOT, join, then PIVOT. The syntax of which will depend on your DBMS.

Comment: no there are 10 associations to the same table and my DBMS is Mysql. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Ragnar921 10 is a bit of a grey area. MySQL doesn't seem to support any nice unpivot/pivot functions. So you'd do UNION's to unpivot, then join, then a series of CASE statements to pivot. This is a bit of a bad smell for the data model though, if you normalize this "ranking" table life would be easier.

Comment: @Austin updated the question, please check.

Comment: @Error_2646 actually changing the data model would be huge pain since this is already implemented solution with ongoing team.

Comment: I see no problem with joining the table multiple times. With an index on item.id (which you should have already, as this seems to be the primary key), you can do a hundred such joins and this would probably still be the best solution.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner could you provide a query please, so i can check with existing

Comment: I don't see a real problem with this data model either. It makes clear that the items are ranked 1 to 4 (well, 10 in your real table) and you cannot rank more items than that. I would probably still not choose it, but it really depends on how the data is used and queried.

Comment: On a side note: It's a bit strange that so many of your columns are null-allowed. You can have an item without a code; you can have a ranking without a search text and without an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining the table multiple times (even many, many times) should not be a problem, as you are joining on the primary key, i.e. you have an index that will be used.

```
select 
  r.id,
  r.search_text,
  i1.item_code as item_code_1,
  i2.item_code as item_code_2,
  i3.item_code as item_code_3,
  i4.item_code as item_code_4
from rankings r
left join item i1 on i1.id = r.first_item_id
left join item i2 on i2.id = r.second_item_id
left join item i3 on i3.id = r.third_item_id
left join item i4 on i4.id = r.forth_item_id
order by r.id;
```

I am using outer joins here, because all your item columns are nullable.